# Вода в Unity3d, фиолетовый фон

Tags: c#, unity3d

Импортировал воду из стандартных ассетов, добавил на сцену, происходит вот что
Пробовал все возможные ассеты, в т.ч. и про, хотя версия персональная. Добавляется, но не работает.
Что не так? [image: Сборище разных ассетов]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выяснилось - просто один глюков Unity. Стоило удалить старую версию(5.3.5 и поставить новую 5.4.1) как всё заработало.